# setTimeout com laço each não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, each

```
count = 1;
$("a.btns").each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent("span").attr("id") == "btn_default") {
        return;
    }

  count++;
these = $(this);

setTimeout(function() {
$(these).click();
  }, 10000 * count);
});
```

O problema deve ser bem simples de resolver, mas to quebrando a cabeça..

Basicamente, procuro rodar cerca de 10 botões na página, que atendem pela classe "btns", e a cada 10 segundos(como defini no timeout), dar um clique no botão(um de cada vez, como é a proposta do código).

Porém na prática, apenas o último botão é clicado todas as vezes.
Parece que em toda a chamada do setTimeout,a o inves do "these" ser cada botão, ele pega o último do laço each.

O que fazer nesse caso?

Obrigado

Comment: O `setTimeout` não mantém o `these` de acordo com o valor que ele continha no momento em que foi chamado. Ele vai pegar sempre a referência atual. Ao final dos primeiros dez segundos, o laço `each` já vai ter acabado e a referência contida em `these` será a do último elemento. E vai ser assim para todas as outras vezes que o `setTimeout` executar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `setTimeout` não mantém a variável `these` de acordo com o valor que ela continha no momento em que foi chamada. Ele vai pegar sempre a referência atual. Ao final dos primeiros dez segundos, o laço `each` já vai ter acabado e a referência contida em `these` será a do último elemento. E vai ser assim para todas as outras vezes que o `setTimeout` executar.

```js
count = 1;
$("a.btns").each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent("span").attr("id") == "btn_default") {
        return;
    }

    count++;
    these = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(these).click();
    }, 1000 * count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(1)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(2)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(3)"></a>
</span>
```

Esse é um problema comum que acontece quando não entendemos o que são as [*closures*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) no JavaScript e como ele trabalha com os escopos/contextos das funções.

A solução seria arranjar uma maneira de manter a referência para o elemento do botão na hora de chamar a função dentro do `setTimeout`. Você pode jogar o seu `setTimeout` para uma função auxiliar parametrizada (mantendo `these` em um contexto diferente, sem relação com o contexto da função em que foi chamado):

```js
count = 1;
$("a.btns").each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent("span").attr("id") == "btn_default") {
        return;
    }

    count++;
    these = $(this);
    clickTimeout(these, 1000 * count);
});

function clickTimeout(el, time){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).click();
    }, time);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(1)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(2)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(3)"></a>
</span>
```

Ou você pode utilizar o método [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) do Javascript para trocar o contexto do `this` dentro da função que está sendo passada para o `setTimeout`. Podemos passar a variável `these` como o novo `this` da função e usá-lo ali dentro sem perder sua referência:

```js
count = 1;
$("a.btns").each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent("span").attr("id") == "btn_default") {
        return;
    }

    count++;
    these = $(this);

    setTimeout((function(el) {
        this.click();
    }).bind(these), 1000 * count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(1)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(2)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(3)"></a>
</span>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

---

### EDIÇÃO

No JavaScript ES6 foram inseridas as variáveis do tipo [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) e [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const). Elas adicionam uma funcionalidade interessante chamada [Temporal Dead Zones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#Temporal_dead_zone), que permite que elas conservem o valor que elas continham no escopo quando foram executadas. [É um conceito um pouco difícil de entender](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified).

Na prática, seu `each` passa a funcionar da maneira esperada com apenas uma pequena alteração no código original:

```js
count = 1;
$("a.btns").each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent("span").attr("id") == "btn_default") {
        return;
    }

    count++;
    const these = $(this); // <--- Agora utiliza "const"

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(these).click();
    }, 1000 * count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(1)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(2)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(3)"></a>
</span>
```

Observe que agora a variável `these` é declarada utilizando `const`. Dessa maneira, seu código fica mais intuitivo e fácil de entender, sem precisar quebrá-lo (e, assim, afetar a legibilidade) para levar em conta os [fechamentos e os contextos do `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Por último, temos ainda outra maneira de solucionar o seu problema, utilizando [*arrow functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), que também são uma nova funcionalidade do JavaScript ES6:

```js
count = 1;
$("a.btns").each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent("span").attr("id") == "btn_default") {
        return;
    }

    count++;

    setTimeout(() => $(this).click(), 1000 * count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(1)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(2)"></a>
</span>
<span>
  <a class="btns" onclick="console.log(3)"></a>
</span>
```

As *arrow functions* não têm o seu próprio contexto `this`, e portanto utilizam o `this` do contexto léxico que está logo acima. Isso quer dizer que quando sua *arrow function* utilizar o `$(this)`, ela estará acessando o objeto `this` da iteração do `each` na qual foi chamada, conservando também a referência do elemento do botão.

Comment: Parabéns pela completa resposta, e também por apresentar soluções alternativas. Show de bola, um grande abraço!